# AngularJS route to secured resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, spring-security

How to check in Angular that resource is secured by Spring Security? I mean when I go to secured resources by address bar application redirect to login page. It is good. But when I go to secured resource by Angular route - angular crashed ("RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"). It is also well because this resources is secured. The question is how to check it in Angular to not obtain error?

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/pages/about.html", "/about")
            .access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')").and().formLogin()
            .loginPage("/register").failureUrl("/register?error")
            .usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/register?logout")
            .and().csrf()
            .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");
}
```

in js

```
.when('/about', {
    templateUrl : 'pages/about.html',
    controller  : 'aboutController'
})
```

Comment: hmmm, when you are authenticated with a user with ADMIN_ROLE  your app work fine ? you can see de page about.html ?

Comment: Angularjs is used to do single page applications. All the application should be in the same page. Routes is just used to show different views of the same page and not different pages. Spring Security should secure access to methods and not urls. All the part after # is not sent to the server, it is only seen by the browser.

Comment: That means : "/about" in your js is not the same thing in your Security configuration